# auto hide a div / flash message after few seconds using css3 react

Tags: javascript, ajax, css, reactjs

I comparatively new to React environment .I have wrote a very basic component for bookmarking feature.

Basically clicking upon `favourite icon`,

`it sends an ajax call > create a record in the db > on ajax success show a flash message "Page added to favourites."`

Its a toggle button, so upon clicking on it again ,

`it sends an ajax call > delete the record in the db > on ajax success i show a flash message "Page removed from favourites."`

Here is the component i wrote which works perfectly. But what i do not like is, using the `setTimeOut` function to hide the flash message. I fell like there must be other way (may be css) to achieve the same in React way.

```js
import React, {
  PropTypes
} from 'react';
import {
  Component
} from 'aplus-base';
import axios from 'axios';

const API = "http://localhost:3000/favourites/toggle"
const API2 = "http://localhost:3000/favourites/current_bookmark_status"

@Component
export default class Bookmark extends React.Component {
  static styles = require('./bookmark.sass')

  state = {
    bookmarked: '',
    message: "",
    alert: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  toggle() {
    const querystring = require('querystring')
    axios.post(API, querystring.stringify({
        current_page_key: '/marketing'
      }), {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          bookmarked: response.data.bookmarked,
          alert: true
        });
        const message = response.data.bookmarked ? "Added to Favourites" : "Removed from Favourites"
        this.setState({
          message
        })
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            alert: false
          });
        }, 2000);
      })

  }
  fetchData = () => {
    const querystring = require('querystring')
    axios.post(API2, querystring.stringify({
        current_page_key: '/marketing'
      }), {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          bookmarked: response.data.bookmarked
        });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      i className = {
        this.state.bookmarked ? "icon icon-bookmarked" : "icon icon-bookmark"
      }
      onClick = {
        this.toggle.bind(this)
      }
      /> <
      div styleName = {
        `result ${this.state.alert ? "alert-shown": "alert-hidden"}`
      } > {
        this.state.message
      } <
      /div>     <
      /div>
    )
  }
}
```

```css
.icon display: inline-block width: 30px height: 30px background: no-repeat center background-size: contain vertical-align: middle &.icon-bookmark background-image: url(../assets/bookmark.png) transition: all 1s linear &.icon-bookmarked background-image: url(../assets/bookmarked.png) transition: all 1s linear .result position: fixed top: 0 left: 40% width: 20% box-sizing: border-box padding: 4px text-align: center font-weight: bold .alert-shown opacity: 1;
transition: all 250ms linear;
.alert-hidden opacity: 0;
transition: all 250ms linear;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261963/how-to-rerun-css3-animations-in-react-js/45262059#45262059

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CSS3 animations` to hide your element after the specified time. Since am not able to run and see your code output, am not able to give the exact code snippet. You can dynamically add classes on your request success (you can use the same way you currently use, or there is a npm package called `classnames`) that will add those animations to show and fade your element.

Lets take this example:

```
animation: FadeAnimation 1s ease-in .2s forwards;
```

this will execute the FadeAnimation for 1 second with the ease-in style after 0.2 seconds the class is attached.

```
@keyframes FadeAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

This will transition the element from visible state to hidden state. You can add in between stages to your animation, by including some animation properties at respective percentage based on which place you want it to occur. You can similarly do it for removal as well.

Have a look at [CSS3 Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/reyxwj8n/ Here is a sample using query, but when clicking on the button for the second time it does not works.

Comment: hope you are working on react. During the onclick event, use setState callback to remove the class, once the transition is done.

Comment: thats not going to work, as it quickly removes the class before the animation is done. Thats what happening with my jquery approach also.

Comment: Here is the fiddle with react , http://jsfiddle.net/2kqv6fo7/6/ . Click button only works for the first time, then the message never got visible as the class is already added.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to *show an overlay with React and hide it with css* after a few seconds and I bumped into your question, so I thought I show you how I made it. The answer of @jefree-sujit was of great help to me.

The end result is that actually we are showing a hidden overlay, then showing it via an animation in css, and then hiding it again.

So, in my `render` method I show my component like that:

`{isPostFulfilled && <SuccessDisplay />}`

*(this part can be different depending on how you make your API calls, I use [react-redux-fetch](https://github.com/hirviid/react-redux-fetch) so I'm getting pending/fulfilled/rejected properties for my calls).*

My `SuccessDisplay` component uses `styled-components` and is practically the overlay:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { BootstrapIcon } from 'skin';

export const Styling = styled.div`
  .success {
    animation: hide-animation 0.6s ease-in 0s;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 100000;

    .ok-icon {
      font-size: 50px;
      cursor: default;
      opacity: 0.9;
      position: absolute;
      top: 48%;
      left: 48%;
      color: green;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    @keyframes hide-animation {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    }
  }
`;

const SuccessDisplay = () => (
  <Styling>
    <div className="success">
      <BootstrapIcon icon="ok" className="ok-icon" />
    </div>
  </Styling>
);

export default SuccessDisplay;
```

The `BootstrapIcon` is rendering `react-bootstrap`'s glyphicons.

The deal with the `animation` in this css snippet is that:
it will run the `hide-animation` for `0.6 seconds`, using the `ease-in` style (within those 0.6 seconds) and all this kicks in `0 seconds` after the styles are loaded (instantly).

The important part is to set the `visibility: hidden` in our initial styles as well, since this is where we start from and where we're going to. After the animation ends (after 0.6 seconds) then we're falling back to our initial styles.

Hope this helps somebody in the future!