# How to rerun css3 animations in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to show a quick flash message for few seconds after ajax success. The message should be auto hidden after 1/2 seconds.

As reactjs does not promote for dom manipulation, I want to achieve the same using css3 animation.

Here is simple demo i prepared,

When you click on the button for the first time it shows the message, but on the subsequent click it does not do anything.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  }
  showFlashMessage() {
    this.setState({
      show: true
    })
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      div className = {
        `message ${this.state.show ? "fadeOut": ""}`
      } > Hello < /div> <
      button id = "but"
      onClick = {
        this.showFlashMessage.bind(this)
      } > Click Me < /button> <
      /div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Test / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
@keyframes FadeAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.fadeOut {
  animation: FadeAnimation 1s ease-in .4s forwards;
}

.message {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kqv6fo7/9/

I am not sure if there is any other alternatives except css3 .

Any suggestion?

Comment: this is a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250868/auto-hide-a-div-flash-message-after-few-seconds-using-css3-react/45251016#45251016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have answered to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250868/auto-hide-a-div-flash-message-after-few-seconds-using-css3-react/45251016#45251016) also, its the same, try handling with the state change. Since you have mentioned you are using a `toggle button` in your previous question, i have used a similar `checkbox` which will be helpful for you.

I ve made the code work only when the toggle is `checked`, I assume you would need to show some message on `toggle off` too. Do the same, by toggling between two classes. And try to avoid inline function bindings, cuz it will trigger for every render. Instead go for constructor, which will get executed just once when the component is loaded.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      showClass: undefined
    }
    
    this.showFlashMessage = (event) => this._showFlashMessage(event);
  }

  _showFlashMessage(event) {
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show,
      showClass: (!this.state.show ? "fadeOut": "fadeOut2")
    })
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      div className = {
        `message ${this.state.showClass}`
      } > Hello < /div>
      <button id ="but" onClick = {this.showFlashMessage} > Click Me </button><
      /div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Test / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
@keyframes FadeAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes FadeAnimation2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.fadeOut {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  animation: FadeAnimation 1s ease-in .2s forwards;
}

.fadeOut2 {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  animation: FadeAnimation2 1s ease-in .2s forwards;
}

.message {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: I want it with a button. With checkbox you are removing the fadeout class and then adding the same on the next click. But I want it with every button click. I want to show the div with every state change weather you select or unselect the checkbox. I tried explained the same with my previous thread also.

Comment: I initially implemented with what you have asked earlier, now I have added some tweaks to the code to make it work for you. Let me know if there is any issue. If you need to achieve with something else, you are welcome too.

Comment: Your solution works fine now, but still i am wondering if this is the best possible way to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the end of the animation and change the state there.

See this:

[How can I animate a react.js component onclick and detect the end of the animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111813/how-can-i-animate-a-react-js-component-onclick-and-detect-the-end-of-the-animati)